# How to index an array?

Tags: php, arrays, json, indexed

I have a multi dimensional array, like this:

```
array('name' => array('title'=>'Title','date'=>'Created'))
```

I store it as JSON 'array', and when I decode it, I want to reach every item by its number, so I want an indexed array.

How could I solve this in PHP?

Tim

Comment: Can you provide an example of what an indexed associative array is??

Comment: Precisions needed.
I don't see what you're trying to achieve here.
What are those "items" you're talking about ?

Comment: So, I want to convert this associative array into a numeric array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your last comment Tim, this would achieve what you asked.. but I'm not sure why you would want this based off your initial question.

```
$foo = array('name' => array('title'=>'Title','date'=>'Created'));
$bar = array_values($foo);
print_r($bar); // Array ( [0] => Array ( [title] => Title [date] => Created ) )
```

Comment: You wanted an ordered list(numeric array) of values from your hash (associative array). I suppose this is helpful in order to loop through the results in some order, but you lose the benefit of having the key.  You could also just generate a separate array of keys that could be re-ordered more easily, by using array_keys($foo) instead.